# Simple .NET CMS with following features?

Tags: .net, content-management-system, blogs

I am going to be posting some kinds of 1)*articles* and 2)*my program  related faqs* on my site and would like some centralized CMS (with WYSIWYG html preferably but not really too important) for that, also support of some openids would be preferable, I am not sure whether they come with that (comments etc).

Also I plan to have 3) *blog* with preferably good comment abilities (open ids welcome again). I thought at first a blog engine might be enough but I think 1) and 2) could be not default option for blog engines.

Since I believe its a little bigger than blog, and way less then big CMS I belive there might be some intermediate answer here. I have looked at Orchard CMS for example, and it appears a little more advanced then my needs are.

DB is irrelevant, but id prefer postgreSQL, sql server, mysql in that order.

**EDIT:** I can see that mostly `N2cms`, `Umbraco`, `Orchard` and `DotNetNuke` are referenced everywhere. If someone could point me on a comparison those or compare at least some of them regarding simplicity and some other aspects it would be great. I also plan to use DISQUS for comments I think, but I believe its pretty easy to integrate with in any CMS or?

Question is becoming less and less concrete, but I believe most non specific CMS quesitons are and they arent usually closed here.

Comment: This has been asked here in the past, and I'll try to find the post, but in the meantime check FunnelWeb: http://funnelweblog.com

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711229/umbraco-alternative

Comment: It is interesting, in that topic OP says he keeps running into problems with Umbraco. As for funnelweb, is there a comparison of it with anything? Ive read comparison of orchard and umbraco, thanks for linking that. What I already can see, is that project is very fresh and there arent that many sample usages.

Comment: FunnelWeb is very new, true. It's mostly blogs using it right bow but it definitely supports stand-alone "pages" rather than posts. I don't believe anyone has done a proper feature matrix anywhere yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [Umbraco](http://umbraco.com), which is a highly scalable CMS. You can configure Umbraco to run in any of the DB's you want. It's also relatively easy to learn if you get their Umbraco TV subscription which goes around $30/month. Umbraco also has a bunch of plugins that would help for comments(I would recommend UComment if you're looking for one).

Umbraco doesn't have WYSIWYG HTML generation out of the box but you could always use an external program to generate the HTML templates and import them into Umbraco.

Comment: could you maybe compare it with some alternatives? or its been generally good for you and you didn't compare it with anything?

Comment: I've tried out DotNetNuke as well, and it's fine for developers with a .NET background. Skinning is quite easy with DNN. However I still prefer Umbraco's workflow as there's far less clutter.